# The LINQ expression '...' could not be translated

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0, ef-core-6.0

I am getting the following error;

The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Rule>()\r\n    .Where(r => True && True && False || r.Title.Contains(\r\n        value: \"i\", \r\n        comparisonType: OrdinalIgnoreCase) && True && True && True)' could not be translated. Additional information: Translation of method 'string.Contains' failed. If this method can be mapped to your custom function, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2132413 for more information. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

When I am using the following code;

```
return x => (!model.Status.HasValue || x.Status == model.Status)
                    && (!model.RuleTypeId.HasValue || x.RuleTypeId == model.RuleTypeId)
                    && (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.Title) || x.Title.Contains(model.Title, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    && (!model.UpdateDateFrom.HasValue || x.UpdateDate >= model.UpdateDateFrom)
                    && (!model.UpdateDateTo.HasValue || x.UpdateDate <= model.UpdateDateTo)
                    && (!model.UpdatedBy.HasValue || x.UpdatedBy == model.UpdatedBy);
```

Used version : .net 6, efcore 6.0.11

The problem has been solved when I used;

> EF.Functions.Like(x.Title, $"%{model.Title}%")

Instead of x.Title.Contains(...). Why I am not able use contains?

Comment: Try `Contains` without the comparisonType parameter.

Comment: Since LINQ to EF (Core) translates method calls into SQL (or potentially other database query languages), case sensitivity of contains is controlled by the database engine and table column settings, and your ability to force e.g. insensitivity depends on something like `ToUpper` or `ToLower` being supported analogous to how it would be done in SQL. See also [Collations and Case Sensitivity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/collations-and-case-sensitivity).

Answer (score -4):

`.Contains` has no equivalent in SQL, so it is impossible to translate it into a clause to be evaluated on the server.

Comment: It has: `x.Contains(y)` is `x LIKE '%y%'. I think the issue is the comparisonType parameter as the LIKE operator doesn’t has something like that – though some comparisonTypes can be approximated by specifying a collation.